# How do you edit an edit?

Tags: support, editing

Is there a way to undo an edit?
I entered in the edit body MathJax code and I don't think it is allowed in there.

Thanks.

Comment: You can always make another edit to correct whatever your first edit broke.

Comment: I see. Thanks. I'll try that.

Comment: If you view the edit history (by clicking on the "Edited [...]" hyperlink at the bottom of the post) there are hyperlinks to rollback to a previous version. eg, [this link](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1530820/revisions) is at the bottom of the post. If you look at revion 1, then in the blue bar, there's a link to roll back.